# how to animate scaling an image over time via webkit

Tags: css, image, webkit, transition

I have collection of images in a simple gallery that I want to transform from small to large smoothly on mouseover.
I am currently doing this by revealing the actual size of an image when the mouse is over but forcing it to a certain size when it is not and hiding the real size with display:none.

I want to include some webkit transformations **to do this over a 1s period** to improve the transitions. I understand webkit is to transform an element between two states however is there anyway I can make this happen.

I also want to avoid JavaScript.

```
.reveal a .preview
{
    display: none;
}

.reveal a:hover .preview
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.reveal img
{
    background: #fff
    padding: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
}

.reveal li
{
    background: #eee;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.reveal .preview
{
    border-color: #000;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without the html (ie jsfiddle) it's hard for me to insert the solution within your code.. but here is a generic solution http://jsfiddle.net/9QVae/2/

```
img
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    transition:width 1s, height 1s;
    -moz-transition:width 1s, height 1s, -moz-transform 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition:width 1s, height 1s, -webkit-transform 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition:width 1s, height 1s, -o-transform 1s; /* Opera */
}
```

on hover:

```
img:hover
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

so the [trick](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) is to specify the css property you want to add an effect to (ie width)
then specify the duration of the event ie `transition:width 1s;` then you specify the final dimension under the `:hover` selector

**note:** `transition` does **not** work on IE

Comment: Hey thanks this is lovely. Although this is a little different to what I wanted. Everything needs to shift about to make it work and I loose the top padding. Also my images are all different sizes and using 'auto' doesn't remedy this.

Comment: i figured as much.. if you give me a jsfiddle i'm pretty sure I can show you exactly what to do